# python2.7 error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get an error when I run this python script.

```
def thousandthPrime():
    count=0
    candidate=5 #candidates for prime no. these are all odd no.s Since starts at 5 therefore we find 998th prime no. as 2 and 3 are already prime no.s
    while(True):
        #print 'Checking =',candidate
        for i in range(2,candidate/2): #if any number from 2 to candidate/2 can divide candidate with remainder = 0 then candidate is not a prime no.
            if(candidate%i==0):
                break
        if i==(candidate/2)-1: # If none divide it perfectly, i will reach candidate/2-1 eventually. So, this is a prime number.
            count+=1
            print 'No. of prime no.s found excluding 2 and 3 =',count, '--->',candidate
        if(count==998):
            print 'The thousandth prime is',candidate
            break
        candidate+=2 # to go to the next odd number.
```

I get this error:

```
File "/home/.../xxx.py", line 19, in thousandthPrime
    if i==(candidate/2)-1: # If none divide it perfectly, i will reach candidate/2-1 eventually. So, this is a prime number.
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

But if I replace, candidate/2 with just candidate, I get no errors, although it increases some unnecessary calculations.

Comment: Already explained in docs: [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: I'm not so sure. The docs make it sounds like this only happens if the variable is assigned to in local scope. Here, `i` is never assigned to, just used for comparison.

Comment: Yes, @CDspace's answer seems to be on the right track. This link to the UnboundLocalError doc is not relevant in this instance.

Comment: @ely `i` **is** assigned to, that's the thing. `for i in ...` is assignment to `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple if you step through it:

```
>>> candidate=5
>>> candidate/2
2
>>> range(2, 2)
[]
>>> for i in []: print(i)
>>> i
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Your loop is empty, so you never step into it, so `i` never gets defined.

As pointed out in comments elsewhere, you really only need to check up to `int(sqrt(candidate))`, not `candidate/2`. But you'll still have the same problem if you do that: `int(sqrt(5))` is still `2`.

---

This means this test:

```
if i==(candidate/2)-1:
```

… is trying to access a variable that hasn't been defined.

But if you step back and think about what you're really testing, in pseudocode, it's this:

```
if I finished the loop without break:
```

And Python has a built-in way to say that: the `else` clause on loops.

In fact, the tutorial section [`break` and `continue` Statements, and `else` Clauses on Loops](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) which introduces this feature has an example very similar to yours:

```
>>> for n in range(2, 10):
...     for x in range(2, n):
...         if n % x == 0:
...             print n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x
...             break
...     else:
...         # loop fell through without finding a factor
...         print n, 'is a prime number'
```

The `else` clause will be executed if you finish looping without a `break`—which includes the case where the loop iterator was empty.

---

So, in your code:

```
while(True):
    #print 'Checking =',candidate
    for i in range(2,candidate/2): #if any number from 2 to candidate/2 can divide candidate with remainder = 0 then candidate is not a prime no.
        if(candidate%i==0):
            break
    else: # If none divide it perfectly, i will reach candidate/2-1 eventually. So, this is a prime number.
        count+=1
        print 'No. of prime no.s found excluding 2 and 3 =',count, '--->',candidate
```

---

If you want more detail on exactly how `else` works than the tutorial gives, see the reference docs on [`while`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) and [`for`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

Answer (score 6):

You're declaring `candidate` as an integer. Thus `candidate/2` is also an integer, specifically 2. Then your `range(2, candidate/2)` is `range(2, 2)` which is nothing, so `i` is never initialized. You'll need to set `candidate=5.0` to make it a float and all should be well.

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the comments, simply re-defining `candidate` will give you a type error, but it should be enough to get you on track. Note, `range(x, y)` expects integers, you you may have to convert to an integer again after the division or limiting calculation using `int()`. Also, you may want to look into why the `math.sqrt` function was mentioned related to primality testing

Answer (score -1):

### Scope of a variable

That's not a problem in this code, which even if it's unpretty to use the variable `i` outside its intended scope (inside the `for` construct), i should remain defined after finishing the for loop, provided...

### Checking edge cases

... the for loop should run at least once to **declare** the name `i` for some variable.

As this doesn't happen, you are getting an UnboundLocalError.

### Quick fix

You can fix this by declaring the i variable just before the for loop, in case it doesn't ever run (a simple `i = 2`)

### Recommended steps

As the Python Zen itself says that *explicit is better than implicit*, by using  different variable for the result you want to keep after the break you're making this value *explicit* instead of *implicit* to the `i` variable after the loop.

Example:

```
def thousandthPrime():
    count = 0
    candidate = 5 # candidates for prime no. these are all odd no.s Since starts at 5 therefore we find 998th prime no. as 2 and 3 are already prime no.s
    while(True):
        # print 'Checking =',candidate
        useful_divider = 2
        for i in range(2, candidate / 2): # if any number from 2 to candidate/2 can divide candidate with remainder = 0 then candidate is not a prime no.
            if candidate % i == 0:
                useful_divider = i
                break
            if useful_divider == (candidate / 2) - 1: # If none divide it perfectly, useful_divider will reach candidate/2-1 eventually. So, this is a prime number.
            count+=1
            print 'No. of prime no.s found excluding 2 and 3 =',count, '--->',candidate
        # And so on...
        # ... and so on :)
```